# .HTACCESS y Redireccionamiento a nuevo dominio con condicionamiento

Tags: .htaccess

Tengo un portal web en WordPress hosteado en un server profesional y que responde a las URL:

1. www.portalweb.subdominio.cu
2. www.portalweb.cu

Esto se debe a un proxy reverso.

He logrado redirigir el tráfico con .htaccess, pero no he logrado lo que quiero que es lo siguiente:

Redirigir todo el tráfico de la (URL 1) a la (URL 2) excepto el backend de WordPress de manera que todos los visitantes accedan por la (URL 2) y los admin y editores puedan acceder al backend por la (URL 1).

- Visitantes accedan por www.portalweb.cu
- Editores accedan por www.portalweb.subdominio.cu/backend

¿Alguna idea de cómo podría hacerse?

Comment: ¿Las URLs del backend de WordPress tienen algún patrón común? Por ejemplo, ¿son todas del tipo miweb.com/admin/loquesea?

Comment: Vamos a dar esta pregunta por resuelta porque a la verdad eso que quiero hacer no va a funcionar debido al estado de configuración de las opciones de wordpress y los enlaces permanentes. Definitivamente trataré de encontrar otra manera para cumplir mi objetivo sin redireccionar.

Answer (score 0):

Para estas 2 redirecciones:

1. `www.portalweb.subdominio.cu` (no `/backend`) → `www.portalweb.cu`
2. `www.portalweb.cu/backend` → `www.portalweb.subdominio.cu/backend`

Hay 2 condiciones que verificar: cuál es el host y cuál es la ruta.
Todos los `RewriteCond` son condiciones que, si se cumplen, permiten ejecutar la siguiente `RewriteRule` (si es que también coincide).

```python
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Todo excepto backend a www.portalweb.cu
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}     ^www\.portalweb\.subdominio\.cu$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^backend(?:/|$)   [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)             http://www.portalweb.cu/$1   [R,L]

# www.portalweb.cu/backend a www.portalweb.subdominio.cu/backend
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          ^www\.portalweb\.cu$   [NC]
RewriteRule ^(backend(?:/.*|$))   http://www.portalweb.subdominio.cu/$1   [NC,R,L]
```

Estas reglas son bastante evidentes. Los flags significan:

- `[NC]` No Case. Ignorar mayúsculas y minúsculas.
- `[L]` Last. No seguir intentando más reglas.
- `[R]` Redirect. Redireccionar a otra URL (en vez de reescribir). Este flag hace una redireccion temporal (302). Si te interesa una permanente, luego de que hayas verificado que *todo* funciona bien, se puede cambiar por `[R=301]`.

Comment: Esto promete ser lo que quiero lograr, lo probaré enla mañana del lunes. Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: He estado buscando documentación para aprender sobre estas reglas de servidor pero lo que encuentro resulta ser probre o inutil para comprenderlas... esta información me ha sido util realmente ahora comienzo a entender un poco mejor.

Comment: @Leonardo me alegro... y es que en realidad, no hay mucho que aprender sobre `RewriteCond` y `RewriteRule` (que todo está explicado en la documentación de Apache)... El tema principal es que para las reglas usan expresiones regulares, que no te las va a enseñar ahí. Hay algunos enlaces [en la wiki de la etiqueta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info), o podés leer o hacer preguntas en el sitio etiquetadas [tag:regex].